# Why does OpenCV+GStreamer lags exactly two seconds behind real time?

Tags: video, rtsp, opencv, gstreamer

I'm trying to capture live feed through an h264 camera on RTSP protocol. On a terminal, the following *gst-launch-1.0* command gives almost real-time feed:

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=rtsp://IP:PORT/live uridecodebin0::source::latency=0
```

When I put in the converted uri into OpenCV VideoCapture, it works but is always exactly two seconds behind. The following two URLs seem to give the same result:

```
cv2.VideoCapture("uridecodebin uri=rtsp://IP:PORT/live latency=0 ! videoconvert ! appsink")
cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://IP:PORT/live", cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
```

Is there something like OpenCV is maintaining a buffer of the video? Or is the converted URL missing something? If the first case is true, can the buffer be removed?

Answer (score 0):

I had difficulty with getting that 2 seconds latency as well.

As i understand it at this moment, your "latency=0" flag isn't parsed due to Gstreamer defaulting to rtspsrc without parameters due to not being able to parse your pipe with uridecodebin. Try running your program with increasing levels of GST_DEBUG  like so :"GST_DEBUG=1 ./yourprogram", "GST_DEBUG=2 ./yourprogram", etc..   to see where it goes wrong. In my case I ended up using

```
    std::string pipe =  "rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.1.113:554/user=admin_password=_channel=1_stream=1.sdp latency=0 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! appsink";
    cv::VideoCapture cap(pipe, cv::CAP_GSTREAMER);
```

While I know this question is from a couple of months ago, I hope this answer will help others.